# Google App Engine and Java Version

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Hi i installed java 7 and using eclipse Juno on ubuntu.i installed google app engine plugins(1.7.0 sdk) .i created a web project HelloWorld1 when i deploy it on google it gives me 500 internal server error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 in google app engine .i go through some queries but unable to solved out.i am new to ubuntu.can any one please help how to solve this error.please help me.

i again tried now i am using jre System library java-6-openjdk-i386  with appengine 1.7.0 sdk
but still i am getting the same error 500 internal server error Unsupported major.minor version 51.0.
please some one help for running my first project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Java 7 support has arrived as of last month. This have have cleared up the problem you were having.

"In App Engine 1.7.5, released in February of 2013, the Java runtime added optional support for Java 7 as an experimental feature. "

"In a future release, support for Java 6 will be removed, so it is a good idea to try running your existing Java 6-based app in the new Java 7 runtime while it is still optional."

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/java7

Answer (score 3):

You must compile your project with Java SE 6, GAE does not support Java SE 7.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview) you see all informations about the Java environment.